# DataTable c# "Specified cast is not valid" error

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, runtime-error

I have to sum the integer values of the specific column in `DataTable`.

What I've done:

```
DataTable dt = GetFilledDataTable();
foreach( var x in dt.AsEnumerable() )
{
   z+=(int)x["ColumnName"];
}
```

I obtain the error:

> Specified cast is not valid

I'm totally sure, that the value in `x["ColumnName"]` is `1445`

**SOLUTION**

As @stuartd in his comment suggested, i've used `int.Parse(x["columnName"].ToString())`

Comment: But are you totally sure that '1445' is an int?

Comment: Have you tried int.parse(x["ColumnName"]) ?

Comment: `int.Parse(x["columnName"].ToString())` even

Comment: @stuartd i believe the OP wants the value to be an int rather than string

Comment: @Jaroslaw BTW since you're using Linq to DataSet, you don't you use `x.Field<int>("ColumnName")`?

Comment: @auburg erm, the `ToString()` is inside the `int.Parse(…)` - `int.Parse` takes a string as an argument, whereas the indexer on a DataRow [returns an object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5(v=vs.110).aspx)). So OP would need to call `ToString()` on the object returned by `x["ColumnName"]` in order to use `int.Parse`

Comment: TY all - using `int.Parse(x[...].ToString())` works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over rows and then use generic Field method:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
{
   var value = dataRow.Field<int>("ColumnName");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Convert.ToInt32` instead of type cast:

```
DataTable dt = GetFilledDataTable();
foreach( var x in dt.AsEnumerable() )
{
   z+=Convert.ToInt32(x["ColumnName"]);
}
```

This will work fast if your value is really `int` and perform necessary conversions if it's `uint` or parse if it's `string`.